# Correct way to handle the data from a post with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, post

I have an issue converting the data coming from a server with post with JQuery because of the data received from the server is a "type of" [object Object]

Notes: the data received from the server is supposed to be a JSON

I tried to convert directly the response from the server to JSON I have an error, thus I tried first to convert the response into a string and then into JSON but this fails as well, the code is the following:

```
// THE FOLLOWING CODE IS FROM A HTML PAGE

  $('#login-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    let $form = $(this),
      email = $form.find("input[name='email']").val(),
      password = $form.find("input[name='password']").val(),
      url = $form.attr('action');
    // Send the data using post
    let posting = $.post(url, {useremail: email, userpassword: password}, 
          function(data, status, xhr){ // catch response from the server
            let responseString = JSON.stringify(data); // convert response from [object Object] to String
            let responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseString); // convert response string to JSON type
    });

  });
```

```
/// THE FOLLOWING CODE IS FROM THE SERVER SIDE
res.json({
   status: 'some status',
   message: 'some message'

});
```

The expected results are that the data is converted to a JSON dictionary

Comment: `JSON.parse` converts a json response to a javascript object.

Comment: Yes but not, as I mentioned in the question I`ve tried that but does not work

Comment: Missing bracket on your server response. Please check that the server returns a well formed json.

Comment: Sorry my bad I fixed that in the question, the code has the related brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is already sending the response in JSON, so on the frontend (Client side) there is no need to `JSON.stringify()` response and again using `JSON.parse()` on it.

Try to log data, you should be able to access the status and message directly using the data response.

So try removing the following line from your .js file

```
let responseString = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Instead, try

```
console.log(data.status);
console.log(data.message);
```

Check if you get the appropriate log on the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()` so your code will look like this:

```
let responseJSON;
$('#login-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    let $form = $(this),
      email = $form.find("input[name='email']").val(),
      password = $form.find("input[name='password']").val(),
      url = $form.attr('action');
    // Send the data using post
    let posting = $.post(url, {useremail: email, userpassword: password}, 
          function(data, status, xhr){ // catch response from the server
            let responseString = JSON.stringify(data); // convert response from [object Object] to String
            responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseString); // convert response string to JSON type
    });
  });

  console.log(responseJSON.message);
  if(responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('message') {
    console.log(responseJSON['message']);
  } else {
    console.log("'message' not found in response");
  }
```

Both will work. And if by "Dictionary" you mean key-value pairs with unique keys, JSON object keys should always be unique. You can check whether a key exists in an object using the `hasOwnProperty()` method as described above.

Comment: This answer is useful and works, but Dave's answer is more properly for my question because of it points to my mistake, but anyway thanks a lot for this help

Answer (score 0):

As long as your server is returning valid JSON content, the data returned by jQuery POST will be a JavaScript JSON object you don't need to process, for example:

```
$.post(url, data, function(data, status, xhr) {
    // data is a JSON object with the server response
    let id = data.id;
    alert("Your new post was saved with id: " + id);
});
```

Note how I access the data directly.

Please check this simple jsfiddle I created for a quick demo; it uses a dummy API to make a POST request:

https://jsfiddle.net/danyalejandro/x46wzjdy/11/

Comment: Thanks a lot Dany